# Grafana showing "too many outstanding requests" error while querying loki dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, amazon-eks, grafana-loki, grafana-api

I am trying to use loki and grafana for generating and visualizing log-based metrics. I have created a Grafana dashboard using the loki filters. While clicking the refresh button, all dashboards fail with the error "too many outstanding requests" and display no data. Refer to the screenshot attached.
[image]
I deployed grafana and loki to the EKS cluster.

Is there a parameter I can adjust to resolve the issue? I examined the pod/deployment configurations but found nothing pertinent.

Please assist.

Comment: I also faced this issue, and updated my Loki configuration according to some of the examples at https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/5123 and it seemed to help.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was fixed after adjusting the "max_outstanding_per_tenant" parameter in Loki configuration.

Answer (score 6):

You can change default limits for some Loki internal variables. Here is an example of a tested config that works fine on 4 core virtual machine with simple file storage.

```
query_scheduler:
  max_outstanding_requests_per_tenant: 4096
frontend:
  max_outstanding_per_tenant: 4096
query_range:
  parallelise_shardable_queries: true
limits_config:
  split_queries_by_interval: 15m
  max_query_parallelism: 32
```

More details on this issue: https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/5123

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding a `max_outstanding_requests_per_tenant` value to the `local-config.yaml` file, which is the default Loki config file. The file is stored in the official Docker image at `/etc/loki/local-config.yaml`. So I mounted a `local-config.yaml` file to that location:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

query_scheduler:
  max_outstanding_requests_per_tenant: 2048
```